# How to find the git tag of a release version in the azure artifact feed?

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops

In our azure devops artifact feed we have many packages, each with many versions. I'd like to programmatically find the git tag of a version of a package. In the artifact feed, I can see a link to the code that was used to build the package. However, I cannot seem to find this link/git tag using the API. Does anyone know how I can find the code used to build the package? I want to use this to automatically generate change logs.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use API "[**Artifact Details - Get Package Version Provenance**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/artifact-details/get-package-version-provenance?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)" to get the details of the specified package version.
[image]

**Note:**
In this API, unlike the **`feedId`**, the **`packageId`** and **`packageVersionId`** cannot directly use the name of the package and package version. You must use the GUID Id to the two input parameters.

- To get the GUID Id of a specified package, you can use the API "[**Artifact Details - Get Packages**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/artifact-details/get-packages?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)" to list all the packages from the specified feed. From the response of this API, you can get the **`packageId`** based on the package name.
- Similarly, to get the GUID Id of a specified package version, you can use the API "[**Artifact Details - Get Package Versions**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/artifact-details/get-package-versions?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)" to list all the package versions from the specified package. From the response of this API, you can get the **`packageVersionId`** based on the package version.